# Magento 2 : gtm - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined

Tags: google-analytics, magento2, google-tag-manager, magento2.4

Since yesterday, in my Magento 2 website, am seeing the below error in the console when i try it click on any links and it not redirecting to respective links. please check below image.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCuDA.png)

if i change the GTM tag or disable the GTM configuration in magento 2, then console issue is not coming and those links are working fine.

Any suggestion, what might be the issue, how can i solve this issue.

Comment: I think we need to review what is in the tag. It's common JS error which the code can not select the dom you want and cause the error

Comment: HI @darrelltw, could you explain what we can check from the tag vice

Comment: Do you know what it is inside in the Google Tag Manager? There should be some tags and their type is `custom html`